# object positioning with style.position

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to be able to move an object from one position to another using buttons for example 3 buttons left right and center that always put the object at the exact same positions everytime.

I have tried using style.position="absolute" but it moves left or right or whatever position depending on it last position never the same three positions.

Which one of static, absolute, fixed, relative, inherit would be best to use in this case? and is it possible to get an example of how a particular object would be set to a particular position thanks in advance

Comment: Set up a demo on jsfiddle.net with what you've tried.

Comment: Why don't you try each one?  That way you will have the information for future endeavors.

Comment: Questions without a single line of code are often not answerable. There are a lot of details you didn't share.

Comment: A lot of your questions are getting down votes, please be more careful when asking question, so that others can help you more easily. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`position: absolute` tells the browser HOW to position your element, but not WHERE to position your element.  You still need to position your element by setting `left` or `right` and `top` or `bottom` values in your css.

Given some markup:

```
<button id="left">LEFT</button>
<button id="right">RIGHT</button>
<button id="center">CENTER</button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="thingy"/>
</div>​
```

and some styles:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#thingy {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #f69;
}​
```

You can move the thingy this way:

```
var thingy = document.getElementById('thingy');

document.getElementById('left').onclick = function() {
    thingy.style.position = 'absolute';
    thingy.style.right = null;
    thingy.style.left = 0;
};

document.getElementById('right').onclick = function() {
    thingy.style.position = 'absolute';
    thingy.style.left = null;
    thingy.style.right = 0;
};

document.getElementById('center').onclick = function() {
    thingy.style.position = 'inherit';
    thingy.style.left = null;
    thingy.style.right = null;
};
​
```

Code is posted at: http://jsfiddle.net/TXWfh/1/

Comment: Also remember that for style absolute to work, an element must be a child of an element that is either `absolute`, or `relative`

Comment: @JuanMendes, good point. Your comment came through before the code, but I think I've got that covered. :)

Comment: In your case, it's fine, because the absolutely positioned `div` is a child of the `body`. I'm just warning the OP, in case his divs are nested.

Comment: @JuanMendes, actually, in my code the div is not a child of the body and the containing element IS marked "relative"...

Comment: ooops, I guess I was thinking of Xeon06's answer, which I commented on :p

Comment: lol, no worries! It was just a great point made in the wrong place!

Answer (score 1):

You could make it work with `absolute`, but I think relative might work best in your case.

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" id="left" value="Left">
<input type="button" id="middle" value="Middle">
<input type="button" id="right" value="Right">
```

CSS

```
#test {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

input {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");

document.getElementById("left").onclick = function() {
    test.style.left = "0px";
};

document.getElementById("middle").onclick = function() {
    test.style.left = "250px";
};

document.getElementById("right").onclick = function() {
    test.style.left = "500px";
};
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPeeN/)

Comment: Modified the example to show an alternative using CSS for the positioning. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/MPeeN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are trying to do, but it really doesn't matter if you don't have a lot of surrounding html code that can get affected by your choice of position value.

following 3 fiddles do same things but with subtle difference that they have different value for position attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/9uQT8/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/9uQT8/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/9uQT8/5/

try clicking left center right. and see. I used jQuery though, super cool JS framework.

Comment: I am sorry my questions are not clear I am new to this. How would you use this with svg instead of css?